# Перестал запускаться проект на Net Core

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

При попытке запустить Net.Core приложение из VS стала появляться такая ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В указанном файле следующая информация:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И ничего не помогает. Не могу запустить проект и все тут.
До выполнения самого проекта, как я понимаю, дело не доходит - не выполняется ни одной строчки кода.
Гугление тоже не дало результатов.

Может кто-то помочь?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте запускать приложение не из-под веб сервера IIS, а через консольную команду.

```
cd WebUi
dotnet run
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]